# What to do about evolution cards that don't work well in solo games?

Tags: archipelago, archipelago-solo-exp

Archipelago has some evolution cards that fit quite well in a multiplayer game, but in the solo game, they make little or no sense.

For example, the "Financial Advisor" gives you 1 florin for every 5 florin you reveal to your opponents. How should this be played in a solo match? It does nothing? I get 1 florin for every 5 I have? Should I remove it from the solo game?

Something similar happens with the "Queen" card. She adds 2 free florin to the order of play bid which is skipped in solo games. Again, should I remove it? Should I simply assume it does nothing?

There are many other examples. How do you deal with those cards? Are there any special rules about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several cards can be left out of the solo game, as they only have an effect when there are multiple players:

- King
- Queen
- Thief
- Spy
- Pirate

The main problem with this is that this could change the balance of the game due to the backs of these cards (during crisis).  A middle ground may be to remove them and replace them with the next card when they are placed face up (but disregard the new crisis now showing).

Also, the designer has mentioned (*although I can't find it anywhere*) that the assassin should not be allowed to kill off your own character cards.

Comment: I liked your "middle ground" suggestion. It also makes the setup as simple as the original Archipelago game.